# Delete row in trigger (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I've got a trigger on update, that should delete the row *OLD**, but I don't know the table structure.
So I've tried using information_schema to grab columns names, but it's really slow.

Is it possible to perform the deletion without knowledge about table structure?

**UPD:**
Trigger should accept row of any table, so trigger function cannot know anything about the table before it will be invoked.

**UPD2:**
This works well for me:

```
EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM ' || tablename || ' WHERE ctid=$1' USING OLD.ctid;
```

Comment: Why do you need this? An update is actualy an insert of a new version and a delete of the the old version of a record. There is no need for an extra delete by this trigger, the trigger will never find a record because the record is already gone.

Comment: The trigger is an UPDATE trigger, so there won't be a DELETE. But the real question is: why doesn't the application use a DELETE when it wants to delete a row

Comment: Yes, it's an update trigger, but it wants to delete the old version of the updated record, check ctid.